# How can I add watermark text and Images in React Native Camera (RN Camera)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I want to add a watermark to React native Camera. Whenever I click/shoot the images the watermarked image should be saved.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground ??

Comment: I need mostly dynamic text

Comment: What do you mean - _mostly dynamic text_ ?

Comment: Yes I need fully dynamic text as a watermark on Image

Comment: @Shreyak I haven't tried it, but you could try loading the image into a canvas, then adding the text to the canvas, and finally saving that canvas image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [react-native-image-marker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-marker) and it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).